# Voting/unvoting system with AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I implemented a voting/unvoting system on Django using AJAX like this:

[image: Unvoted]

[image: Voted!]

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def vote(request):
    post_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']

    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        current_user = request.user.id

    try:
        voted = Vote.objects.get(post=post, user=current_user)
    except Vote.DoesNotExist:
        voted = None

    # Voting code

    if not voted:
        Vote.objects.get_or_create(post=post, user=request.user)
        post.points = post.vote_set.all().count()
        post.save()
        print("voted!")

    return HttpResponse(post.points)

@login_required
def unvote(request):
    post_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']

    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        current_user = request.user.id

    try:
        voted = Vote.objects.get(post=post, user=current_user)
    except Vote.DoesNotExist:
        voted = None

    # Voting code

    if voted:
        Vote.objects.filter(post=post, user=request.user).delete()
        post.points = post.vote_set.all().count()
        post.save()
        print("unvoted!")

    return HttpResponse(post.points)
```

**main.js**

```
// Voting
$('.vote').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid = $(this).attr("data-postid");
    $.get('/vote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){ //Send post_id to vote view
        $('#points' + postid).html(data); // Data changed element
        $('#' + postid).attr('class', 'voted');
    });
});

// Unvoting
$('.voted').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid = $(this).attr("data-postid");
    $.get('/unvote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){ //Send post_id to unvote view
        $('#points' + postid).html(data); // Data changed element
        $('#' + postid).attr('class', 'vote');
    });
});
```

Voting works fine, but I have to refresh the page to unvote. As well as unvoting and then vote again. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you load your page there is only one element has the `vote` or `voted` class. You should add a class, let's say `votable`, and then do something like this:

```
$('.votable').click(function(){
    var element = $(this),
        postid = element.attr("data-postid");

    if (element.hasClass('voted')) {
        // Unvoting
        $.get('/unvote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data) { //Send post_id to unvote view
            $('#points' + postid).html(data); // Data changed element
            $('#' + postid).removeClass('voted');
        }); 
    } else {
        // Voting
        $.get('/vote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data) { //Send post_id to vote view
            $('#points' + postid).html(data); // Data changed element
            $('#' + postid).addClass('voted');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The click() function binding on the click event is a direct binding which will only attach the on click event handler to elements that already exist, it will neither bind to elements created in the future nor on elements who you are selecting via a property you are dynamically adding or removing (in this case, class).

The following .on() method will function throughout dynamic changes.

```
$(document).on('click','.vote', function() {
    //Do Stuff
});
```

As a general rule accessing an element via a specific class that you expect to be dynamically adding and removing via code is questionable practice. You should access the element via id or name or a class you will not be adding and removing, it simplifies the overall structure.

If you access your element via `$(document).on('click','#yourId', function(){});` it will cleanup some possible problems you may run into.